# std::thread crash in Debug mode (Work in run) with Netbeans/Cygwin

Tags: c++, netbeans, gdb, cygwin

I'm trying to debug (GDB) my application developped with Cygwin under Windows.
When I debug this, I got "Signal received: ? (Unknown signal)" when the thread is created and the program stop.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
using namespace std;

void ConnectionTimer()
{

}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    cout<<"Before thread creation"<<endl;  
    std::thread t( ConnectionTimer);
    cout<<"After thread creation"<<endl;          
    t.join();
    cout<<"After join"<<endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

The debugger stop at the line 
`status = NtCreateMutant (&mtx, MUTEX_ALL_ACCESS, &attr, bInitialOwner);`in kernel32.cc.

It work as expected in run mode but crash in debug.
Result in run mode :

```
Before thread creation
After thread creation
After join
```

Result in debug mode (before crash):

```
Before thread creation
```

Any ideas what i'm missing ?

***EDIT***

If I comment thread related lines, it work properly.

[Call Stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AICt.png)

[Signal caught which cause crash](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thtth.png)

[Discard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8cEFy.png)

**Configuration :**
Cygwin 3.1.4-1 on W10 under GDB 8.2.1-1, compiled with g++ (GCC) 9.2.0-3

Comment: *but crash in debug* -- If it crashes in debug mode, then you should be able to debug it.  Get rid of the `cout` statement inside the thread function and try again.

Comment: The cout is just for the example. It crash at the thread creation for no reasons. When I go step by step the program crash even before entering the thread function.

Comment: Again, get rid of the `cout` statement.  Run your program at "full speed", not step by step.  Running step by step in a MT program is a quick way to get things all messed up due to timing issues.  This is one reason why MT programs are not trivial.

Comment: It actually work at "full speed" with or without the cout. The problem is that I need to use debug mode for a bigger application which is using threads as the example.

Comment: Same result with join : work in run mode, but not in debug mode

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue (int the updated code) with visual Studio. It works as intended in Relase and Debug mode with both x64 and x86 architectures. Maybe your compiler is outdated and containes a bug?

Comment: There's something else to this problem. The code shown should work fine. Do you compile and link any other source files? Maybe some static or global initialization are crashing elsewhere. Try with an empty main. Can you show a stack trace of the error?

Comment: it works fine on Cygwin 3.1.4 on W10 under GDB  8.2.1, compiled with g++ (GCC) 9.2.0

Comment: I got same configuration than you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason of the crash.

My antivirus (Trend) was blocking the program, I had to create an exception for the exe and everything is now working fine.

Comment: AVs are the main cause of problem for Cygwin https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda